# Don't understand the need of "grad" in lrCostFunction.m

Tags: neural-network, octave

Coding the **lrCostFunction.m** in Octave for the course *Machine Learning in Coursera (Neural Networks)* "**ex3**". I don't get why we need to obtain "**grad**". Anybody has a clue?
Thx in advance

Comment: Please include the related lrCostFunction.m code into the question itself. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Code Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) section of the formatting help page. Not everyone has access to the "_Machine Learning in Coursera (Neural Networks) ex3_".

Comment: This is a little bit like asking " I have a book and don't understand the equation on page 3"

Answer (score 1):

Grad refers to the 'gradient' of the cost function.

Your objective is to minimize the cost function. In order to do that, most optimisation algorithms also need to know the equation that gives its gradient at each point, so that they can use it to move the next search in a direction that makes it more likely that the cost function will be at a lower value.

Specifically, since the gradient at a point is defined as the direction of maximal rate of '*increase*' in the underlying function, typically optimisation algorithms use the current point and take a small step in the *reverse* direction to that indicated by the gradient.

In any case, since you're asking an abstract optimisation algorithm to optimise parameters such that a cost function is minimized by making use of its gradient at each step, you need to provide all of those inputs to the algorithm. Hence why you need to calculate 'grad' value as well as the value of the cost function itself at each point.